# C++: How can lock-free data structures be implemented in C++ if std::atomic_flag is the only lock-free atomic type?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, lock-free

Typical way of implementing lock-free data structures is using atomic CAS operations, such as `std::compare_exchange_strong` or `std::compare_exchange_weak`. The example of this technique's usage can be seen in Antony Williams' "C++ Concurrency in Action", where a lock-free stack is implemented. The stack is implemented as a linked list with `std::atomic<node*>` head pointer. CAS operations are performed on this pointer during pushs and pops. But C++ standard guarantees that only `std::atomic_flag` is lock-free, other atomic types, including `std::atomic<T*>`, may be not lock-free.

1) do I understand correctly that if `std::atomic<T*>` is not lock-free (`std::atomic::is_lock_free()` returns false), then data structure based on CAS operations on `std::atomic<T*>` is not lock-free?

2) If yes, then, what are alternative ways to implement lock-free data structures on C++ if `std::atomic_flag` is the only lock-free atomic type for some compiler?

Comment: Is it a huge problem for you in real life if some operations are not lock-free? Have you benchmarked your application and determined that the "non-lock-free-ness" is causing an actual performance problem? If not, why do you care?

Comment: @JesperJuhl The question is just out of curiosity, currently I'm not aware of the platform with non-lock-free `std::atomic<void*>` type.

Comment: `atomic_flag` is not generally recommended unless your use-case is so simple that you only need the limited operations it provides.  Related: [Why does C/C++ not have a atomic flag test\_and\_clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77929368)

Answer (score 5):

The only likely reason for a compiler not to have a lock free implementation of an atomic type is if the processor doesn't have atomic operations. I'm not aware of a modern processor where this is the case.

If the processor doesn't support atomic operations you probably have no choice but to use mutexes, semaphores or similar synchronisation primitives

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, a compiler does have one lock-free implementation: for `std::atomic_flag`. The question is what if it is the _only_ lock-free implementation. Or do you mean that all modern processors are likely to have atomic operations for data that fits into a single word (`void*`, for example)?

Comment: I'm no expert on the availability of cpu instructions but I'd be very surprised if any cpu capable of multi threading didn't have the requisite atomic operations for words