# Is test-and-set (or other atomic RMW operation) a privileged instruction on any architecture?

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system, cpu-architecture, futex

Hardware provides atomic instructions like test-and-set, compare-and-swap, load-linked-store-conditional. Are these privileged instructions? That is, can only the OS execute them (and thus requiring a system call)?

I thought they are not privileged and can be called in user space. But http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/ossg/IPC_sync/ts.html seems to suggest otherwise. But then, [futex(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/futex), under certain conditions, can achieve locking without a system call, which means it must execute the instruction (like test-and-set) without privilege.

Contradiction? If so, which is right?

Comment: I think you need to state the CPU architecture. As far as I know Intel does not have a `Test_and_Set (TS)` instruction. Intel CPU's have the atomics, they just lack that particular instruction. Maybe it is a field in a machine specific register/control register and reading/writing it is protected? Ping @PeterCordes.

Comment: Right, I believe x86 has the compare-swap `cmpxchg` instruction. How can I ping him?

Comment: You can get my attention by posting questions in the `[assembly]` tag :P

Comment: @jww: x86 has had `lock bts` since 386.  [`bts` = Bit test and set](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BTS.html).

Comment: Thanks @Peter. The author specifically states the instruction is `ts`. Are you aware of an arch that comes from? Or are they using a hypothetical instruction set?

Comment: @jww: I don't think they're talking about a specific architecture; they're talking about the primitive operation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set), regardless of how it's implemented in asm.  In C++11, it's the only one that's required to be lock-free: [C++: How can lock-free data structures be implemented in C++ if std::atomic\_flag is the only lock-free atomic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50825174).  (I don't know of a `ts` instruction on any ISA.  Most are LL/SC, and don't have any single-instruction atomic RMWs.)  It's often called TAS, just like cmpxchg is normally CAS.

Comment: I wondered if they were talking about a hypothetical ISA, but the few higher up / earlier pages give no sign of that.  It's pure C.  But sure, you could have a hypothetical crappy ISA with a privileged TS instruction (and no other atomic primitives) which makes it impossible to write good lockless multi-threaded user-space code, and hard to multi-thread efficiently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**That page is wrong**.  It seems to be claiming that lock-free atomic operations are privileged on ISAs in general, but that is not the case.  I've never heard of one where atomic test-and-set or any other lock-free operation required kernel mode.

If that was the case, it would require [C++11 lock-free atomic read-modify-write operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) to compile to system calls, but they don't on x86, ARM, AArch64, MIPS, PowerPC, or any other normal CPU.  (try it on https://godbolt.org/).

It would also make "light-weight" locking (which tries to take the lock without a system call) impossible.  (http://preshing.com/20111124/always-use-a-lightweight-mutex/)

**Normal ISAs allow user-space to do atomic RMW operations, on memory shared between threads or even between separate processes.**  I'm not aware of a mechanism for disabling atomic RMW for user-space on x86.  Even if there is such a thing on any ISA, it's not the normal mode of operation.

Read-only or write-only accesses are usually naturally atomic on aligned locations on all ISAs, up to a certain width ([Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86)), but atomic RMW does need hardware support.

---

On x86, TAS is `xchg` (a whole byte) or `lock bts` (a single bit), both unprivileged.  ([Documentation for the `lock` prefix](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LOCK.html)).  x86 has a *wide* selection of other atomic operations, like `lock add [mem], reg/immediate`, `lock cmpxchg [mem], reg`, and even `lock xadd [mem], reg` which implements `fetch_add` when the return value is needed.  (See also *[Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num)* for how hardware implements these, and the C++ rules.)

Most RISCs have LL/SC, including ARM, MIPS, and PowerPC, as well as all the older no longer common RISC ISAs.

---

**`futex(2)` is a system call.  If you call it, everything it does is in kernel mode.**

It's the fallback mechanism used by light-weight locking in case there *is* contention, which provides OS-assisted sleep/wake.  So it's not `futex` itself that does anything in user-space, but rather lock implementations built around `futex` can avoid making system calls in the uncontended or low-contention case.

(e.g. spin in user-space a few times in case the lock becomes available.)

This is what the `futex(7)` man page is describing.  But I find it a bit weird to call it a "futex operation" if you don't actually make the system call.  I guess it's operating on memory that kernel code might look at on behalf of other threads that are waiting, so the necessary semantics for modifying memory locations in user-space code depends on `futex`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for this detailed answer! If `futex(7)` does not call `futex(2)` (i.e. no contention), it must use the TAS or other atomic instruction to implement the lock, right? I haven't checked the code for `futex(7)`... I mentioned it in the question since `futex(7)` is a library function, it runs in user space, and so any TAS executed must be in user space.

Comment: @flow2k: Yes, atomic RMW in userspace.  But `futex(7)` is documenting the general concept of how to build a lock or other operation around `futex(2)`.  There is no library function called `futex()` other than the system call wrapper; if there was it would be called `futex(3)`.  Anyway yes, the whole point of this answer is that `futex(2)` is how you sleep if you find the lock already taken in an implementation like this x86 asm spinlock (which works in userspace): [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246263)

Comment: I have never seen a processor where bit test and set operations are privileged instructions. No wonder CS students are so confused.